# UserName - Password check function returning "false"

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm having some trouble managing my login for a website. I've tried several different methods and queries which all seem to lead to the same problem: the method I use to check `username` and `password` always returns `false`.

To make it easier to understand, here's what I'm trying to do:

- Controller file calls view page and prompts user for `username` and `password`
- I'm using a `callback` function to set a rule for the form
- the `callback` function calls Model method
- Model method returns `TRUE` if login details are correct and `FALSE` otherwise.

Apparently it always returns `FALSE` as the login never works ...

I'm using CodeIgniter.

Controller file:

```
class Login extends CI_Controller {

  public function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    $this->load->library(array('form_validation', 'session'));
  }

  public function index()
  {
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'callback_login_check[password]');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
      //loading view as long as it is not correct
      $this->load->view('login');
    } else {
      //temporary successful login page
      $this->load->view('success');
    }
  }

  public function login_check($usr, $pwd)
  {
    $this->load->database();
    $this->load->model('EZ_Query');

    $result = $this->EZ_Query->get_user_details($usr, $pwd);

    if ($result == TRUE) {
      return TRUE;
    } else {
      $this->form_validation->set_message('login_check', 'Password does not match Username');
      return FALSE;
    }
  }
}
```

Model file:

```
class EZ_Query extends CI_Model {

  public function get_user_details($usr, $pwd)
  {
    $sql = "SELECT *
              FROM PROFIL
              WHERE USER = '$usr'
              AND MDP = '$pwd'";

    $query = $this->db->query($sql);

    if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {
      $row = $query->row();

      //session variables
      $data = array('name' => $row->NOMPROFIL,
                    'fname' => $row->PRENOMPROFIL,
                    'type' => $row->TYPEPROFIL);
      $this->session->set_userdata($data);

            return TRUE;
    } else {
      return FALSE;
    }
  }
}
```

Less useful, here's part of login view page:

```
<body>
    <?php
      echo validation_errors();
      echo form_open('Login');
      echo form_label('Username', 'username');
      echo form_input('username')."<br />";
      echo form_label('Password', 'password');
      echo form_password('password')."<br />";
      echo form_submit('sumbit', 'Enter');
      echo form_close();
    ?>
  </body>
```

Sorry for bad english, and thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you not hash user passwords before storing?

Comment: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming

Comment: why you use callback like `callback_login_check[password]` this?

Comment: @Shihas what do you mean? i need to use both username and password variables in the query to check if they are correct. This way, i can use both without problem

Comment: @JonStirling i will, but not yet. For now i'm just making the basic functionnalities before adding the details.

Comment: @wolfgang1983 changed it in the source code :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have changed a couple of things on here for you to try

I hope you are using a good hash for passwords **NOT MD5** use http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

Filename: Login.php

```
<?php

class Login extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        $this->load->library(array('form_validation', 'session'));
        // Autoload the session because you may need it else where
    }

    public function index() {
        // remove the word password from callback as it on the username 
        // login all ways good to use required

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|callback_login_check');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {

            //loading view as long as it is not correct
            $this->load->view('login');

        } else {

            //temporary successful login page
            $this->load->view('success');
        }
    }

    public function login_check()
    {
        $usr = $this->input->post('username');
        $pwd = $this->input->post('password');

        $this->load->database(); // Autoload database best.

        // Filename of model should be Ez_query.php and same with class only first letter upper case

        $this->load->model('ez_query'); 

        $result = $this->ez_query->get_user_details($usr, $pwd);

        if ($result == TRUE) {
            return TRUE;
        } else {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('login_check', 'Password does not match Username');
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Amen on the hashing Wolfgang. I see a lot of login controllers here that dont use it

Comment: Thanks for your help, it works great! I'm using sha1 for the password encryption.

Comment: Just, can you explain to me why using the callback function with a second parameter doesn't work?

Comment: Because on the user name you had `callback_login_check[password]` it should of been `callback_login_check[username]` it gets the input name for that set rules. I think why. You would of need to create a set rules for password if need to `callback_login_check[password]`

Comment: `$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|callback_login_check[password]');`  I just find it's easy for me to use input->post() etc.